# Restoring a saved AWS Amplify Profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have not used AWS Amplify for a few years and last time I used it I save the profile in a CSV file and it has the following fields in it.

[image]

I'm setting up Amplify again on a new machine and I'm wonder if I should just add this configuratino to a `config` file as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html).

In other words save the contents of the CSV file into `~/.aws/config`.

Or is there a more "Updated" way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Since it's a new machine I first had to reinstall the amplify CLI.

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Then add the amplify credentials again.

In order to do this I first create a new Angular project ran `amplify init` from the root project directory folder.

It outputs the following.

```
Project information
| Name: test
| Environment: dev
| Default editor: Visual Studio Code
| App type: javascript
| Javascript framework: angular
| Source Directory Path: src
| Distribution Directory Path: dist
| Build Command: npm run-script build
| Start Command: ng serve

? Initialize the project with the above configuration? Yes
```

Then for authentication method it asks this:

```
? Select the authentication method you want to use: (Use arrow keys)
❯ AWS profile
```

I selected `AWS profile`.

It then asks whether we want to setup a new user.  I said no.

```
? Setup new user (Y/n) n
```

It then asks for credentials.

```
? Setup new user No
? accessKeyId:  ********************
? secretAccessKey:  ****************************************
? region: ***
```

The amplify setup is now restored using the saved credentials.